# Add a specific number of days in a datetime. How to specify the format?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using python and I have a datetime value in the format: `2018-02-20 00:00:00+00:00` and I want to add 10 days in this datetime.

How can I suppose to achieve this?

My current code is the following but it's not working:

```
sorted_sections_id_timestamp = [datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 20, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 23, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)]

for index in range(0,len(sorted_sections_id_timestamp)):
   redo_timestamp = sorted_sections_id_timestamp[index] + datetime.timedelta(day=10)
```

In case I `print (sorted_sections_id_timestamp[index])` I get the value `2018-02-20 00:00:00+00:00`.

Comment: I think the `redo_timestamp` may be correct, but you're not doing anything with it / putting it anywhere, `sorted_sections_id_timestamp[index]` does not get modified

Comment: @DennisSoemers I'm using it through `rest api` and I get error `http 500`. I tried to print the result and I get nothing. So I suppose that `redo_timestamp` is not correct.

Comment: Owh, and `timedelta` should take a `days` (plural) argument instead of `day`

Comment: @DennisSoemers Thank you! That solves my problem! You can add it as a response to accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
datetime.timedelta()
```

should take plural `days` as argument, instead of singular `day`. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

This results in:

```
sorted_sections_id_timestamp = [datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 20, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 23, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)]

for index in range(0,len(sorted_sections_id_timestamp)):
   redo_timestamp = sorted_sections_id_timestamp[index] + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
```